# apollo-client return loading false always

Tags: apollo

i am working on apollo-client and making a query using the following code snippet.

```
var mapQueriesToProps = ({ ownProps, state })=> {
return {
    data: {
        query: gql`
            query{
               getProjects{
                    _id
                    name
                  }
            }
        `,
        variables: {
         },
        forceFetch: true,
        returnPartialData: true,
    },
  };
};
```

when i was set **returnPartialData : false** then Data have the object with *{loading : true}*. and after fetching the data from the server it becomes true. But the problem is when i set **returnPartialData : true**. Data will show always *{loading : false}*. Even if their is no record in the cache. Is their any solution to get the {loading: true} in the first fetch with returnPartialData: true

Comment: What version of apollo-client and react-apollo are you using?

Comment: thanx for the response. but it has been very long time since i have worked on this